# Java: best way to declare a stack of cards

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I'm trying to make a simple Blackjack application so that I can practice what I have learned from my Java book.

The "project" will never be deployed nor is it "important" as such, just for me to learn, keeping that in mind what do you think is the best way for me to store the pack of cards?

My choices seem to be simple array, double dimension array, hashmap and arraylist.

Once I get my cards in my collection I think the methods I will build will be:

shuffleDeck() - self explanatory
removeCardsFromDeck() - So these cards are "used" for the game
mergeNumberOfDecks(int howMany) - How many decks of cards to merge (eg: 0 or 2 or 4 or 8)

Keeping that in mind which do you think would be the easiest to handle:
simple array, double dimension array, hashmap or arraylist?

Comment: You should consider and evaluate the strengths and weaknesses of your four possibilities. For example, how do you propose to "shuffle" a `HashMap` and what would the keys and values be? How would you remove cards from a "simple array"? Etc.

Comment: I don't understand the interface of `mergeNumberOfDecks`.  Why does it only take even integers?  What happens after you call it with 2?

Comment: @dcsohl, I am just learning this stuff and its a bit too much to look at all 4  as they have wayyy too much information for me to digest so I came asking here as I am sure this has been solved a 100 times over.
tieTYT, it is supposed to take two of these collections and merge them together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the options you've listed, a `List` probably makes the most sense because it's easy to work with and will preserve the order of your deck after shuffling it.

Unless you really want to implement them all yourself, the three methods you mentioned are already implemented.

shuffleDeck(): [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

removeCardsFromDeck():

- For single cards, you can use Collection.remove(Object) and related methods (e.g., List.remove(int index) or `LinkedList.removeFirst()`/`LinkedList.removeLast()` or `Stack.pop()`)  Note that although I'm including Stack as an example, you probably don't want to use it unless you require synchronization.
- For multiple cards, you can use `Collection.removeAll(Collection)`

mergeNumberOfDecks(): there isn't an `exact` analog, but `Collection.addAll(Collection)` will make your job very easy

Keep in mind that List inherits all of Collection's methods, and any class that implements List must define implementations for all of List's methods (including those which are inherited from Collection.

Comment: Thanks, Will look up Java lists on google, I only came across the 4 ways that I posted.

Comment: To clarify, `List` is the interface that `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` (among others) implement.

Comment: Thanks guys, both of you have been awesome so will upvote both of you, dont really know which to pick as the "correct answer" as both are great so I'll just pick the one who answered first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Most stack/deck of cards situations are best solved by the use of a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). Has both List and queue methods and also is a collection so you can do the following.

Shuffle: Done by [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) (If your chosen deque also implements List) See [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) as an example

Remove cards: - Ideally top cards, Deque has `removeFirst()`

Merge: `java.util.collection` has `addAll(Collection)` (so any class that implements collection has this method)

Comment: I have not come to "Deque" as yet, I guess that comes further in my book :) Thanks for the link! I was looking up the methods and I don't see any way to shuffle it though... am I missing something?

Comment: Note that `Deque` is only the Interface, to Shuffle use an class that also implements `List` then you can use `Collections.shuffle(List)`

Comment: Thanks guys, both of you have been awesome so will upvote both of you, dont really know which to pick as the "correct answer" as both are great so I'll just pick the one who answered first. Thanks again!